# Getting Date Time created of a file in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that looks something like this:

```
<TemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <a href='<%#Eval("FilePathUrl")%>'>FileName</a>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <a href='<%#Eval(sysUtilities.GetFilePath("FilePathLocation") & "FilePathUrl")%>'>FileDateTime</a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateColumn>
```

The file is located at `sysUtilities.GetFilePath("FilePathLocation")`

sysUtilities is a class in the App_Code folder
GetFilePath is method

I need help with the syntax
How can I display the file's **date time created** in the gridView (by that I mean what is the correct syntax for):

```
<a href='<%#Eval(sysUtilities.GetFilePath("FilePathLocation") & "FilePathUrl")%>'>FileDateTime</a>
```

Comment: what object does your sysUtilities.GetFilePath("FilePathLocation") returns?

Comment: its folder path value from the webconfig .... something like "C:\Data\Invoices"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                      <a href='<%#Eval(sysUtilities.GetFilePath("FilePathLocation") & "FilePathUrl")%>'>
                        <%#System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(sysUtilities.GetFilePath("FilePathLocation") & Eval("FilePathUrl").ToString())%>
                      </a>
                   </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-creation-modification-time/ for several examples on how to retrieve the file time.
You can either use the FileInfo class or the File class, both of them exposing the same properties for retrieving the creation date time

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Markup

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Created At">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="FileCreationTime" runat="server"
            Text='<%# GetFileCreatedTime(Eval(FilePathLocation), Eval(FilePathUrl) ) %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Code-behind

```
Protected Function GetFileCreatedTime(location As Object, url As Object) As String
    Dim path As String = sysUtilities.GetFilePath(location.ToString()) & url.ToString()
    Dim fi1 As FileInfo = New FileInfo(path)
    If fi1.Exists Then
        Return fi1.CreationTime.ToString()
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

On an unrelated side-note, you are using `asp:DataGrid` and not <strike>`asp:GridView`</strike>.